# Stalemate or checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, stalemate

I have a rook, a queen and my king while my opponent has only 2 pawns and a king left.

The situation is complicated because they cannot move anything, except for a single pawn move. But if they move that pawn their king is checked by my queen. Is this situation stalemate or checkmate?

```
8/8/8/6rk/8/5qPK/7P/8 w - - 0 1
```

Comment: I looks like stalemate, but I'm not sure if I read your diagram correctly. Look here for instructions on how to make nice diagrams: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/279/

Comment: If they are not in check then they aren't be checkmated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the situation is as in the diagram below, it is stalemate. You correctly noticed that white has no legal moves: any potential move would put the white king into check, which is not allowed. Furthermore in the position the white king is not attacked, so it is stalemate (not mate).

```
       8/8/8/6rk/8/5qPK/7P/8 w - - 0 1
```

Comment: pawn have move but it is in direct check so it will not mate

Comment: @PrashantValanda: No, you cannot move the pawn, because it would put your king in check. A situation like this is called (absolute) pin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_(chess)#Absolute_pin